# Pi Zero and Pi with UART connected: crash on linked device power on

Tags: pi-zero-w, power-supply, pi-pico-w

I have a Pico W running some app, and I use a Zero W to log (via UART) what is going on for debugging purposes.

The Zero W is configured so that UART0 is the primary UART, and the [UART pins](https://pinout.xyz/) are connected to the Pico W's [UART pins](https://pico.pinout.xyz/):

- Zero W pin 6 (GND) – Pico W pin 3 (GND)
- Zero W pin 8 (UART TX) – Pico W pin 2 (UART0 RX)
- Zero W pin 10 (UART RX) – Pico W pin 1 (UART0 TX)

Both devices are connected to a small USB hub with a power switch for each port.

Now, if the Zero W is turned on, and I switch on the power for the Pico W, the Zero W resets (crashes?) and starts booting again.

Why could this be happening?

Is there some way this comes through the linked GND wire? Is there some way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You might be creating a ground loop with that extra gound wire between the two boards.  They already share a ground via the shared USB power supply so it's not needed.

Comment: This is nonsense. Ground loops can impact sensitive devices e.g. audio but will never affect DC circuitry.

Comment: Your comment is nonsense.  There is an inherent AC element generated by the debounce of the mechanical switch on the USB hub when switched on/off.  And the fact still remains that the extra GND wire is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked without the ground wire, and the problem still occurs. In fact, it still occurs without any wiring between the two Raspberrys. So it is most likely just a problem with the (cheap) USB hub.